# R sum element X in list of vector

Tags: r, list, vector, sum

I just started doing some R script and I can't figure out this problem.

I got a list of vector let say

```
myListOfVector <- list(
     c(1,2), 
     c(1,2), 
     c(1,2), 
     c(1,2)
)
```

what I want is the sum of each X element of each vector that are in my list base on the position of the element
so that if I have 3 vector that contains (a, b, c), I will get the sum of each a, each b and each c in a list or vector

I know that each vector are the same length

What I seek is something like that

```
result <- sum(myListOfVector)
# result must be c(4, 8)
```

Does anybody have an idea ?

The only way I've been able to do it is by using a loop but it take so much time that I can't resign to do it.

I tried some apply and lapply but they don't seem to work like I want it to because all I have is one vector at a time.

Precision : 
The list of vector is returned by a function that I can't modify
I need an efficient solution if possible

Comment: That is not a `list`. Use `list` in place of your first `c`. Then just do `Reduce(\`+\`, myList)`

Comment: Convert to a matrix and use `colSums`.

Comment: Reduce seem to work like a charm :) thank @Frank

Comment: @Frank can you post it as an answer so I can give you the green check ? thank again for the help :)

Comment: For reference, the approach that I was suggesting would be something like: `colSums(do.call(rbind, myListOfVector))`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A list of vectors of the same length can be summed with `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(`+`, myListOfVector)
```

Putting it in a `matrix` and using `colSums` or `rowSums`, as mentioned by @AnandaMahto and @JanLuba, might be faster in some cases; I'm not sure.

---

*Side note*. The example in the OP is not a `list`; instead, it should be constructed like

```
myListOfVector <- list( # ... changing c to list on this line
     c(1,2), 
     c(1,2), 
     c(1,2), 
     c(1,2)
)
```

Comment: If it's already in a `list`, then there might not be any performance advantage. The `colSums` approach may even be slower because you'd have to convert the list to a matrix first.... +1

Answer (score -3):

you should first convert your list to a matrix:

```
mymatrix=matrix(myListOfVector,ncol=2,byrow=T)
```

and then use colSums:

```
colSums(mymatrix)
```